# Laravel, how to filter date in views?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have my views setup more or less like the picture below or can see it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t37g4yzp/1/

How to filter the date in the table base on the user input **Start Date** and **End date** in views?

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
  $get_all_user = User::all();
  return view('userPage.index', compact('get_all_user'));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the way I do date filtering. In order to catch the start data and end date inject the `Request` Object in to the index method.Then I would validate the data submitted and I convert the dates in to `Carbon` Object which give more options like formatting the dates.lastly I use `whereDate` eloquent query function to compare dates. So the end result would be something like this.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  this->validate($request,[
   'start_date' => 'required|date',
   'end_date' => 'required|date|before_or_equal:start_date',
  ]);

  $start = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
  $end = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);

  $get_all_user = User::whereDate('date','<=',$end->format('m-d-y'))
  ->whereDate('date','>=',$start->format('m-d-y'));

  return view('userPage.index', compact('get_all_user'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

```
public function index()
{
        $start = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
        $end = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
        $get_all_user = User::whereDate('created_at','<=',$end)
        ->whereDate('created_at','>=',$start)
        ->get();
        return $get_all_user;
}
```

> Postman

[image]

Note: use `->get();` Otherwise you will get an error.